# Finding the index of a given element using tail recursion

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function to find the index of a given element using tail recursion. Lets say the list contains the numbers `1` through `10`, and I am searching for `5`, then the output should be `4`. The problem I am having is 'counting' using tail recursion. However, I am not even sure if I need to maunally 'count' the number of recursive calls in this case.  I tried using `!!` which does not help because it returns the element in a particular position. I need the the function to return the position of a particular element (the exact opposite).

I have been trying to figure this one out for a hours now.

**Code:**

```
  whatIndex a [] = error "cannot search empty list"
  whatIndex a (x:xs) = foo a as
    where
       foo m [] = error "empty list"
       foo m (y:ys) = if m==y then --get index of y
                         else foo m ys
```

Note: I am trying to implement this without using library functions

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. `Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!` is what I am currently using to learn Haskell. You should not make comments assuming things you are no position to assume. Questions that may seem trivial to you, may not be trivial to others. So I recommend you keep such 'spam' comments to yourself ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your helper function needs an additional parameter for the count.

```
whatIndex a as = foo as 0
  where
    foo [] _ = error "empty list"
    foo (y:ys) c
        | a == y    = c
        | otherwise = foo ys (c+1)
```

BTW, it's better form to give this function a `Maybe` return type instead of using errors. That's how `elemIndex` works too, for good reason. This would look like

```
whatIndex a as = foo as 0
  where
    foo [] _ = Nothing
    foo (y:ys) c
        | a == y    = Just c
        | otherwise = foo ys (c+1)
```

Comment: Also, `foo` doesn't need its first argument - it never changes during recursive calls and you can use the outer `a` instead.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: I am trying to implement this without using library functions

This is not a good idea in general.  A better exercise is this:

1. Figure out how to implement it using library functions.
2. Figure out how to implement whichever library functions you used in step 1 on your own.

This way you're learning three key skills:

- What are the standard library functions, and examples of when they are useful.
- How to break problems into smaller pieces
- How to write basic functions like the ones in the libraries.

In this case, however, your `whatIndex` is more or less the same function as [`elemIndex` in `Data.List`](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/haskell2010-1.1.0.1/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex), so your problem reduces to writing your own version of this library function.

The trick here is that you want to increment a counter while you recurse down the list.  There is a standard technique for writing tail recursive functions, which is called an **accumulating parameter**.  It works like this:

1. You write an *auxiliary* function that, compared to the "front-end" function, takes an extra parameter (or more) to keep track of the extra information.
2. You then define the "real" function as a call to the auxiliary one.

So for `elemIndex`, the auxiliary function would be something like this (with `i` as the accumulating parameter for the current element index):

```
-- I'll leave the blanks for you to fill.
elemIndex' i x []      = ...
elemIndex' i x (x':xs) = ...
```

Then the "driver" function is this:

```
elemIndex x xs = elemIndex 0 x xs
```

But there is a serious problem here that I must mention: **getting this function to perform well in Haskell is tricky**.  Tail recursion is a useful trick in *strict* (non-lazy) functional languages, but not so much in Haskell, because:

1. A tail-recursive function in Haskell can still blow the stack,
2. A non-tail-recursive function can run in constant space.

[This older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144921/is-my-rewritten-foldl-function-optimised/11145179#11145179) shows an example of the second point.

So in your case, a non-tail-recursive solution is probably the easiest one you can give that will run in constant space (i.e., not blow the stack on a long list):

```
elemIndex x xs = elemIndex' x (zip xs [0..])

elemIndex' x pairs = snd (find (\(x', i) -> x == x') pairs)

-- | Combine two lists by pairing together their first elements, their second 
-- elements, etc., until one of the lists runs out.
--
-- EXERCISE: write this function on your own!
zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
zip xs ys = ...

-- | Return the first element x of xs such that pred x == True.  Returns Nothing if
-- there isn't one, Just x if there is one.
--
-- EXERCISE: write this function on your own!
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find pred xs = ...
```