# Recursive definition of this function

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have this function written in Haskell which uses list comprehension.

```
search :: String -> Char -> [Int]
search str letter = [ num | (x, num) <- (zip str [0..]), letter == x]
```

How can I define this same function using recursion and without using library functions like `zip`? I am allowed to use an auxiliary function.

Comment: Is this homework? If it is it's still allowed but it's best to mention it so answers would be more focused on the teaching aspect and not on the straight answer part.

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844296/finding-the-index-of-a-given-element-using-tail-recursion

Comment: It is part of my homework. The quoted code above is what I have written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some suggestion.

A non efficient, but working solution could be found following this recursion scheme.

```
search :: String -> Char -> [Int]
search []     letter = ???
search (x:xs) letter = doSomethingWith (search xs letter)
     where doSomethingWith :: [Int] -> [Int]
           doSomethingWith ns = ???
```

Think about how you could turn the result of the recursive call into the actual result. For instance:

```
search "abcb" 'b' = doSomethingWith (search "bcb" 'b') 
                  = doSomethingWith [0,2]
                  should be
                  [1,3]

search "bbcb" 'b' = doSomethingWith (search "bcb" 'b') 
                  = doSomethingWith [0,2]
                  should be
                  [0,1,3]
```

Note that in `doSomethingWith` you can refer to `x` and check whether it is equal to `letter`.

---

For a better solution, try adding an extra parameter so that the index of the current position is passed around. For instance:

```
search :: String -> Char -> [Int]
search str letter = searchWorker str letter 0  -- initial position is 0

searchWorker :: String -> Char -> Int -> [Int]
searchWorker []     letter position = ???
searchWorker (x:xs) letter position = 
     -- increment position at every recursive call
     doSomethingWith (searchWorker xs letter (position+1))  
     where doSomethingWith :: [Int] -> [Int]
           doSomethingWith ns = ???
```

This simplifies the coding of `doSomethingWith` since the recursive call can now be assumed to produce the correct indices.

```
searchWorker "abcb" 'b' 0 
                  = doSomethingWith (searchWorker "bcb" 'b' 1) 
                  = doSomethingWith [1,3]
                  should be
                  [1,3]

searchWorker "bbcb" 'b' 0 
                  = doSomethingWith (searchWorker "bcb" 'b' 1) 
                  = doSomethingWith [1,3]
                  should be
                  [0,1,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
search :: String -> Char -> [Int]
search str letter = [ num | (x, num) <- (zip str [0..]), letter == x]
```

what this does is it goes along the input list of characters (a string), while increasing the index value by 1 for each new character. And while doing that, it tests to see whether the character is the same as specified, and if so, it produces it (or rather its index).

So we best model this by guarded recursion, which allows us to produce each found character (or its index) as soon as we find it.

```
search str letter = go str <initial-index-value>
   where
```

here we are the masters of our domain, we can have however many parameters to our internal function we want – we're not limited to zipped pairs which are dictated by the list comprehension's `<-` operator. Moreover, we can count by ourselves, creating new indices as we need them.

```
     go [] _ = -- we've reached the end of the input.
               -- we should finish up our output
               ....   -- ok, it's the end of any list - an empty list
     go (x:xs) i 
        | x == letter =
```

we have access to `letter` because `go` is an internal function to our `search`, so we can compare them. Here, we want to produce this index right away

```
                         i :  <a recursive call with updated parameters>
        | otherwise  =
```

nothing to produce here, just make

```
                              <a recursive call to continue the search
                                on input list's tail, with the new
                                 current index value>
```

And we're done.